# SQL - Multiple joins to get fastest time grouped by 3 other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following tables:

```
|  nations  |  athletes   |  events     |  times       |  courses  |
|------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  id       |  id         |  id         |  id          |  id       |
|  name     |  nation_id  |  course_id  |  athlete_id  |  name     |
|           |  name       |  name       |  event_id    |           |
|           |             |             |  time        |           |
```

*- they're all Integers, except the name fields, those are strings -*

---

This is a school project about swim times. I needed to create a complex database with some advanced queries. But I can't seem to figure out how to **get the fastest times** by a nation.

There are some **relationships** to keep in mind:

- `Nation` can have many athletes. `Athlete` belongs to 1 nation.
- `Athlete` can have many times. `Time` belongs to 1 athlete.
- `Courses` can have many events. `Event` belongs to 1 course.
- `Event` can have many times. `Time` belongs to 1 Event.

There are also some **rules** to follow:

- The collection needs to be `ordered by` course_id
- The collection needs to be `ordered by` event_id
- There can be multiple fastest times per event (times that have the same value on the same event), those should be `ordered by` date (the oldest first)

---

Basically: I want to have the fastest times by a nation, ordered by course and than ordered by event. When there are 2 times that have the same value on the same event, than the oldest should be first, but the older times should be there in the collection, though!

---

This is what I have now, but it only gets the best times per event by the athlete. Not by the nation.

```
SELECT * FROM `times` 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            `athlete_id`,
            `event_id`,
        MIN(time) AS time 
        FROM times 
        GROUP BY athlete_id, event_id
    ) b 
    ON  `times`.`athlete_id` = `b`.`athlete_id`
    AND `times`.`event_id`   = `b`.`event_id`
    AND `times`.`time`       = `b`.`time`
    WHERE `times`.`athlete_id` = ?
ORDER BY
    `times`.`event_id` ASC,
    `times`.`date` ASC
```

In this case the question mark represents the id of the athlete you want the best times from. Also in this case there is no `WHERE` clause on the course id, but simply an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Please post the query that you have now, and where you think it might be wrong

Comment: @Brien that would’ve added no value to my quesion. Only more confusion. Trust me

Comment: @Brien I added my current SQL string. I hope my question has more value added now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to create the correct query myself. It's more advanced than the requested query in the question. So therefore this question has downvotes.

The nation id's `73, 212, 214, 226` are (former) Olympic teams from Germany:

- Germany
- West Germany
- East Germany
- United Team of Germany)

**SQL**

```
SELECT * FROM times
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT id, nation_id, nation_id2 FROM athletes
    ) nation_athletes2
    ON nation_athletes2.id = times.athlete_id
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT event_id, gender_id, MIN(time) AS time FROM times
            INNER JOIN (
                SELECT id, nation_id, nation_id2 FROM athletes
                WHERE nation_id IN (73, 212, 214, 226)
                OR nation_id2 IN (73, 212, 214, 226)
            ) nation_athletes
            ON nation_athletes.id = times.athlete_id
        GROUP BY event_id, gender_id
    ) AS fast_times
    ON fast_times.event_id = times.event_id
        AND fast_times.time = times.time
        AND fast_times.gender_id = times.gender_id
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT id, stroke_id, course_id FROM events 
    ) AS events
    ON events.id = times.event_id
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT id, stroke_order FROM strokes
    ) AS strokes
    ON strokes.id = events.stroke_id
WHERE nation_id IN (73, 212, 214, 226)
OR nation_id2 IN (73, 212, 214, 226)
GROUP BY times.gender_id, times.event_id, nation_athletes2.nation_id
ORDER BY times.gender_id, events.course_id, strokes.stroke_order, times.event_id, times.time";
```

This will give me the *fastest times* by a selection of nations. And finally it's grouped by gender and event. If there are multiple *fastest times* by the same gender on the same event, then the one with the oldest date will be in front. It also has the courses table joined in it, because than it will be ordered by course as well (long corse metres, short course metres).

### The final result:

[image]

Comment: I have tried your query on my data [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47abf/4/0) and you can see that the result contains a row with athlete #5 which is NOT in the specified Nation. **This query is incorrect.** I will update my answer with the option to input the Nation you want.

Answer (score 2):

I did this here: [SQL Fiddle v1.0](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c322ff/3/0), [v2.0](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47abf/2/0) (final version [v3.0](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47abf/9/0))

---

First my assumptions/changes:

- you wanted ordering by **date**, but there is no such column in Time, so I added `date DATETIME`
- I chose data type **TIME** for *time* column, but this does not change the query
- changed the names of tables to singular forms (this is a convention AFAIK)

---

Now we would like to assign the best *time* to each *Nation*.

```
  SELECT n2.id, MIN(t2.time)
  FROM Nation n2
    JOIN Athlete a2 ON (a2.nation_id = n2.id)
    JOIN Time t2 ON (t2.athlete_id = a2.id)
  GROUP BY n2.id
```

We use `GROUP BY` and `MIN` aggregation functions, which divides the *time* records among respective *Nation*s and then calculates the best (minimal) time for each group. This way you get the result of the aggregation function but you do not actually know which respective *Athlete* achieved it, only the minimal value in each group. So we need to use this result as a subquery in a main query.

---

The joining of tables and ordering is trivial (just link the IDs & define the ordering of columns in the order of priority), although you should pay attention to the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT n.name, a.name, t.time, t.date, e.name, c.name
FROM Nation n
  JOIN Athlete a ON (a.nation_id = n.id)
  JOIN Time t ON (t.athlete_id = a.id)
  JOIN Event e ON (e.id = t.event_id)
  JOIN Course c ON (c.id = e.course_id)
WHERE (n.id, t.time) IN (
  SELECT n2.id, MIN(t2.time)
  FROM Nation n2
    JOIN Athlete a2 ON (a2.nation_id = n2.id)
    JOIN Time t2 ON (t2.athlete_id = a2.id)
  GROUP BY n2.id
  )
ORDER BY c.id, e.id, t.date
```

The `IN` operator checks, whether the thing on the left side is somewhere in the "collection" (a select in our case) on the right side. You can provide one or more values on the left side, but the amount (and order) has to match the columns in the select on the right side. With only 1 value, you can omit the brackets like `value in (SELECT x.id FROM ...)`.

So for each record of all interconnected data (essentially it is a *time* of a specific *Athlete* at an *Event*) we check whether the actual *time* value of this record AND *Nation* of performing *Athlete* matches the result in the subquery containing best times.

*Note: The subquery is executed for each record of the main select separately*

---

### UPDATE

Including the *Event* besides *Nation* as a factor to distinguish you just include *Event* table in the subquery `GROUP BY` part. This subquery yields the best time for each event separately for each nation.

```
  SELECT n2.id, e2.id, MIN(t2.time)
  FROM Nation n2
    JOIN Athlete a2 ON (a2.nation_id = n2.id)
    JOIN Time t2 ON (t2.athlete_id = a2.id)
    JOIN Event e2 ON (e2.id = t2.event_id)
  GROUP BY n2.id, e2.id
```

This means the final query looks like this:

```
SELECT n.name, a.name, t.time, t.date, e.name, c.name
FROM Nation n
  JOIN Athlete a ON (a.nation_id = n.id)
  JOIN Time t ON (t.athlete_id = a.id)
  JOIN Event e ON (e.id = t.event_id)
  JOIN Course c ON (c.id = e.course_id)
WHERE (n.id, e.id, t.time) IN (
  SELECT n2.id, e2.id, MIN(t2.time)
  FROM Nation n2
    JOIN Athlete a2 ON (a2.nation_id = n2.id)
    JOIN Time t2 ON (t2.athlete_id = a2.id)
    JOIN Event e2 ON (e2.id = t2.event_id)
  GROUP BY n2.id, e2.id
  )
ORDER BY c.id, e.id, t.date
```

You can verify it at [this SQL Fiddle v2.0](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47abf/2/0).

---

### UPDATE #2

OP wants to specify a certain *Nation* for which we want the result, so we just filter the data in the `WHERE` clause adding `AND n.id = ?`.

The resulting query is as follows:

```
SELECT n.name as `Nation name`, c.name as `Course name`, e.name as `Event name`, a.name as `Athlete name`, t.time, t.date
FROM Nation n
  JOIN Athlete a ON (a.nation_id = n.id)
  JOIN Time t ON (t.athlete_id = a.id)
  JOIN Event e ON (e.id = t.event_id)
  JOIN Course c ON (c.id = e.course_id)
WHERE (n.id, e.id, t.time) IN (
  SELECT n2.id, e2.id, MIN(t2.time)
  FROM Nation n2
    JOIN Athlete a2 ON (a2.nation_id = n2.id)
    JOIN Time t2 ON (t2.athlete_id = a2.id)
    JOIN Event e2 ON (e2.id = t2.event_id)
  GROUP BY n2.id, e2.id
  )
  AND n.id = 2 #choose the Nation you want
ORDER BY c.id, e.id, t.date
```

You can verify this in this [SQL Fiddle v3.0](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47abf/9/0) on my test data.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but that doesn't distinguish the different events... Basically I'd like to get a result list like the tables on this wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_German_records_in_swimming . Here you can see that there's a fastest time set on an event by an athlete (times of one event can be the same, in that case there will be two record holders).

Comment: @DerkJanSpeelman Sorry but you specified

"fastest times by a **nation**, ordered by course and than ordered by event"

not mentioning the times should be separately for each _Event_, only for each _Nation_. Check the updated post.

Comment: Fastest time by a nation means: get the fastest times set on an event by an athlete of that certain nation. Take a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_German_records_in_swimming

Comment: @DerkJanSpeelman sorry mate, I do not understand what is wrong with the query v2.0

Comment: I managed to create this SQL: `select * from times inner join (SELECT event_id, MIN(time) AS time FROM times GROUP BY event_id) fastest on times.event_id = fastest.event_id and times.time = fastest.time order by times.event_id asc, times.date asc.` But this query wont let me select the nation.

Comment: I think this is more like what I meant: `SELECT *, MIN(time) AS time FROM times INNER JOIN athletes ON athletes.id = times.athlete_id WHERE nation_id = 73 GROUP BY nation_id, event_id`

Comment: I did marked your answer as the best answer, my answer sucked. It was indeed incorrect. Now, I managed to get it working (with even more complex  grouping, selecting and joining with even more tables and columns). So everyone's happy now. Thank you anyways! (I changed my answer to the query I have now, maybe you'd like to comment if there's anything that I could do better - I have a lot too learn still)